# Adding "double" to List<Double> doubleList

Tags: java

I'm having troubles storing a `Double` into a `List<Double>`.

```
int idx = 0;
String [] documentText = getText();

for(String word : wordList) {
    wordsDistributionList.put(word, new ArrayList<Double>());
}

// ...

if ( wordsDistributionList.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()) == true ) {

    List<Double> dbls = wordsDistributionList.get(word);

    double dbl = ((double)idx/(double)documentText.length);

    dbls.add(new Double(dbl));
    break;
}
```

Doing such a thing results in this:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at worddistribution.DocumentsStatistics.getWordDistribution(DocumentsStatistics.java:57)
    at worddistribution.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Could anybody tell me how I can just store a `Double` in a list?

Comment: `wordsDistributionList.containsKey(word.toLowerCase())` and then `List<Double> dbls = wordsDistributionList.get(word);`. Shouldn't it be `List<Double> dbls = wordsDistributionList.get(word.toLowerCase());` ??

Comment: Why don't trust autoboxing ? `new Double` useless. By the way, ZouZou is right.

Comment: Also `if ( wordsDistributionList.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()) == true )` is redundant, `if ( wordsDistributionList.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()) ` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your List if

```
List<Double> dbls = wordsDistributionList.get(word);
```

returns null then your list will be null when you try to add a Double.

Make sure `wordsDistributionList.get(word)` does not return null if it does then initialize your list explicitly...

Like @ZouZou said try:

```
List<Double> dbls = wordsDistributionList.get(word.toLowerCase());
```

But if that still returns null then you problem is you are not initializing the list you are trying to return.

Comment: Dammit .. I forgot to `.toLowerCase()` it .. I was already thinking I forgot how to Java but it seems that I have forgotten a lot more ..

Answer (score 0):

You're testing if `wordsDistributionList` (which is apparently a Map, not a List) contains the key `word.toLowerCase()`, but getting the value for the key `word`.  This could easily be null.

FYI, instead of

```
if(wordsDistributionList.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()) == true)
```

Just write

```
if(wordsDistributionList.containsKey(word.toLowerCase()))
```

And instead of

```
dbls.add(new Double(dbl));
```

Just write

```
dbls.add(dbl);
```

The latter is called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).